# How to format date in SSRS 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I got in an issue which I failed to accomplish.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Following image shows what I am trying to achieve in a MATRIX report column header.
There are two string rows in the date column which I can't get it worked.

[image]

```
=IIF(Fields!ReportType.Value = "GOAL" or Fields!ReportType.Value = "Test GOAL", Fields!ProcessDt.Value,
IIF(Fields!ReportType.Value = "test1"
or Fields!ReportType.Value = "test-2"
or Fields!ReportType.Value = "test3"
or Fields!ReportType.Value = "test4"
or Fields!ReportType.Value = "test5", Format(Cdate(Fields!ProcessDt.Value), "MMM-yyyy"),  Fields!ProcessDt.Value)
```

Thank you

Comment: What about `...Format(CDate(Fields!ProcessDt.Value), "MMM-yyyy")...` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your newly added question via comment - also known as scope creep.  Please don't extend or ask new questions to an existing question in comments.  If it's a real question, please make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It could help to explicitly cast the field to a Datetime before applying the `Format`:

`...Format(CDate(Fields!ProcessDt.Value), "MMM-yyyy")...`

For your further question, if you want to replace dates with a specific string, you'll need to add another `IIf` statement to the larger statement, something like:

```
..IIf(Fields!ProcessDt.Value = "2/2/2014", "Goal1", IIf(...))...
```

Comment: Hi Ian, I tried to change the original question. I am sorry if it doesn't make sense. Any suggestion?